# Mouse Event in SWT Browser

Tags: java, browser, eclipse-plugin, swt

I have embedded SWT Browser inside Eclipse view.Is it possible to remove mouse event from Browser.i.e. If i created a html file and showing it in SWT Browser,i just want to show the content of html file in browser.No mouse Event should happen when i click on that component.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be possible. Tried removing all `Listener`s from the browser -> no effect. Tried adding my own `Listener`s that do nothing -> no effect.

Comment: Just an idea, but could you put a transparent component over the top of the browser view.